# on iOS 9, firstRectForRange: is returning incorrect value

Tags: ios, uikit, uitextview

In our app, we are using UITextView to display attributedText. And on iOS 9, firstRectForRange: and selectionRectsForRange: methods are returning incorrect values.

Please note that on iOS 10, both the methods return the expected values.

Steps to Reproduce:
1. Set some attributedText on a UITextView.
2. Use the following code to get the frame of a 'text' inside the textview

```
    NSRange range = [textView.attributedText.string rangeOfString:text];
    UITextPosition *beginning = textView.beginningOfDocument;
    UITextPosition *start = [textView positionFromPosition:beginning offset:range.location];
    UITextPosition *end = [textView positionFromPosition:start offset:range.length];
    UITextRange *textRange = [textView textRangeFromPosition:start toPosition:end];
    CGRect rect = [textView firstRectForRange:textRange];
```

3. Note that on iOS 9, firstRectForRange: is not returning the correct value but on iOS 10 it is.